# Why Clang-generated object files contain GNU-labeled section?

Tags: assembly, clang, gnu

Consider this C program:

```c
int main(void) {
    int c = 10;
}
```

And the following actions:

```bash
$ clang -g a.c
$ objdump -D a.out
...
Disassembly of section .note.gnu.property:

0000000000000338 <.note.gnu.property>:
 338:   04 00                   add    $0x0,%al
 33a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 33c:   10 00                   adc    %al,(%rax)
 33e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 340:   05 00 00 00 47          add    $0x47000000,%eax
 345:   4e 55                   rex.WRX push %rbp
 347:   00 02                   add    %al,(%rdx)
 349:   80 00 c0                addb   $0xc0,(%rax)
 34c:   04 00                   add    $0x0,%al
 34e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 350:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
 352:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 354:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)

Disassembly of section .note.gnu.build-id:
...
```

Why does Clang (which, AFAIK, is not GNU property) outputs an object file with sections labeled `.note.gnu.property` and the like?

Comment: It's not "property" in the sense of being "owned". It's a set of properties (features, flags) defined for GNU linux. See also [this mailing list post](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-March/121951.html)